# 2 "onmouseover" break the working of page

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm using a simple code for picture changing on mouse over with;

```
<A href="http://www.x.com" onmouseover="document.Same_size_LINK.src='rist.jpg'" onmouseout="document.Same_size_LINK.src='ist.jpg'">
<IMG SRC="ist.jpg" NAME="Same_size_LINK" WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=85 BORDER=0 >

</A>
```

code. It works perfect but when I try to use two of those code, they both are not working.

```
<A href="http://www.x.com" onmouseover="document.Same_size_LINK.src='r.jpg'" onmouseout="document.Same_size_LINK.src='d.jpg'">
<IMG SRC="d.jpg" NAME="Same_size_LINK" WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=105 BORDER=0 >

</A><br><br>

<A href="http://www.y.com" onmouseover="document.Same_size_LINK.src='rist.jpg'" onmouseout="document.Same_size_LINK.src='ist.jpg'">
<IMG SRC="ist.jpg" NAME="Same_size_LINK" WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=85 BORDER=0 >

</A>
```

I couldn't solve this problem, can you help me?

Comment: Make sure you put quotes around your values and lower case the attributes, to ensure most browsers will work well with your codes. So, instead of this: `WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=85` do this: `width="296" height="85"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need distinguish the names, or better, use document.getElementById and add unique ids to the images

```
<A href="http://www.x.com" onmouseover="document.getElementById('Same_size_LINK-1').src='r.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('Same_size_LINK-1').src='d.jpg'">
<IMG SRC="d.jpg" id="Same_size_LINK-1" WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=105 BORDER=0 >
</A><br><br>

<A href="http://www.y.com" onmouseover="document.document.getElementById('Same_size_LINK-2').src='rist.jpg'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('Same_size_LINK-2').src='ist.jpg'">
<IMG SRC="ist.jpg" id="Same_size_LINK-2" WIDTH=296 HEIGHT=85 BORDER=0 >

</A>
```

Comment: These are the times when JQuery makes life so much easier! :)

Comment: Fact. jQuery would be a much better option for this

Comment: So would CSS (border="0", ugh), but you gotta crawl before you can walk. Or something.

Comment: We all started somewhere... just edited some pages I created 5 years ago... I wanted to know what fool wrote it; looked up the history...

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<a href="http://www.x.com" 
   onmouseover="document.Same_size_LINK_1.src='r.jpg'"
   onmouseout="document.Same_size_LINK_1.src='d.jpg'">
<img src="d.jpg" name="Same_size_LINK_1" width="296" 
   height="105" border="0" />
</a>

<br /><br />

<a href="http://www.y.com" 
   onmouseover="document.Same_size_LINK_2.src='rist.jpg'"
   onmouseout="document.Same_size_LINK_2.src='ist.jpg'">
<img src="ist.jpg" name="Same_size_LINK_2" width="296" 
   height="105" border="0" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome to THE FUTURE! How was your stay in the fallout shelter? Disappointed that the world didn't end in '99?

Second, javascript isn't necessary for this. You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/Eg6wV/

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.x.com" class="image-button" id="button-x"/>
<a href="http://www.y.com" class="image-button" id="button-y"/>​
```

CSS:

```
.image-button{
    display:block;
    width:296px;

}
#button-x{
    height:105px;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    background:url(http://placehold.it/296x105/) no-repeat;
}
#button-x:hover{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/296/105) no-repeat;
}
#button-y{
    height:85px;
    background:url(http://placehold.it/296x85/) no-repeat;
}
#button-y:hover{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/296/85) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: LOL. Sadly, this is not all that uncommon. Your code will not work on IE 5 or earlier, so time-travelers need to be careful.

Comment: @BryanH I suppose we should still be optimizing website content for 800 baud modems too? ;)

Comment: "HOW TO DO ASCII HOVER EFFECT BUTTON! PLEASE TELL!"